# WinRT Caliburn Micro SimpleContainer: registering a decorator in a container

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime, ioc-container, caliburn.micro

How can i register a decorator using caliburn micro for below scenario in WinRT universal app:

I have Caliburn micro container which is register types:

```
_container.RegisterInstance(IService, "", Service);
```

I have created following IService implementation and decorator:

```
public interface IService
{
    void Do();
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public void Do() { }
}

public class LoggedService<T> : IService 
    where T : IService
{
    private T decoratee;
    private ILogger logger;

    public LoggedService(ILogger logger, T decoratee)
    {
        this.decoratee = decoratee;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        logger.Debug("Do()");
        decoratee.Do();
    }
}

public class ProfiledService<T> : IService
    where T : IService
{
    private T decoratee;
    private IProfiler profiler;

    public ProfiledService(IProfiler profiler, T decoratee)
    {
        this.decoratee = decoratee;
        this.profiler = profiler;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        profiler.Start();
        decoratee.Do();
        profiler.Stop();
    }
}
```

How can i register decorator like LoggedService and ProfileService and resolve these depending on which so ever is required conditionally?

Comment: somewhere you will have specified how to construct whatever takes IService. here you can use named registrations or similar methods to differntiate between the types

Comment: However, I do think that your problem demonstrates the limitations of IoC containers. When you start to have to name stuff you are embedding business logic in the container setup

Comment: Can you show me an example of how to achieve this?

Comment: hmm I havent used Caliburn.micro. looks like you can register types with keys? Unity allows Named instances for this kind of thing.

Comment: Here also I can register using a name but then how will that help me?

Comment: ok, it looks to me like caliburn dosnt support construction parameters, which is surprising! you have to use a factory. which solves your problem but not in a very IoC way ie : ContainerBuilder.Register<IWhatever>(w=> new Whatever(new ProfiledService(new Service())))

Comment: ok got it... But what is this Whatever class that you have mentioned.. Is it a separate decorator...

Comment: no I assume you have ViewModels/Controllers/Services which consume IService?

Comment: Yes.. I have VM that consume web services

Comment: yeah, so that's your 'whatever'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SimpleContainer` lives up to it's name here, it doesn't have support for things such as contextual registration. You can use features such as named registrations and `AddHandler` to create custom logic.

They way you would do this is to add an named registration for `Service` and then `AddHandler` for `IService` that instantiates decorator using the container for the actual named registration. It gets a little silly if you have two levels of decorator though.

If you are serious about using decorators or have a lot of them I'd recommend using a more advanced container with specific functionality around decorators.

Comment: There is an other container with "Simple" in the name (that might not live up to its name though) that does have [native support for decorators](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#decorators) though and that's [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, however it may not be optimal. I devised these extension methods that solve the problem.

The idea is that we create a child container, register the decorator implementation as its own service, then unregister the original handler, and register a new handler that uses the child container to lookup the decorator.

The downside is that we create a new child container per decorator we register, however the overhead should be negligible.

```cs
public static SimpleContainer RegisterDecorator(this SimpleContainer container, Type service, Type decorator)
{
    if (!container.HasHandler(service, null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(service));
    }

    var childContainer = container.CreateChildContainer();
    childContainer.RegisterSingleton(decorator, null, decorator);

    container.UnregisterHandler(service, null);
    container.RegisterHandler(service, null, c => childContainer.GetInstance(decorator, null));
    return container;
}

public static SimpleContainer Decorate<TService, TDecorator>(this SimpleContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(TService), typeof(TDecorator));
    return container;
}
```

Usage:

```cs
interface IFoo { }

class A : IFoo { }

class B : IFoo
{
    public B(IFoo x) { }
}

class C : IFoo
{
    public C(IFoo x) { }
}

var container = new SimpleContainer();
container.Singleton<IFoo, A>();
container.Decorate<IFoo, B>();
container.Decorate<IFoo, C>();

var foo = container.GetInstance<IFoo>();
Assert.True(foo is C);
```